# Azure Devops release to IIS fails after AOT blazor wasm

Tags: iis, azure-devops, blazor-webassembly

I have a .NET 7.0 blazor wasm app, that I deploy to a windows server running IIS. This has worked fine, until i added the following to my project (The client, and the project is .net core hosted):

```
<WasmEnableSIMD>true</WasmEnableSIMD>
<RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
```

First i got the following error in my build pipeline:

error NETSDK1147: To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore

So i added a command line step to my build pipeline where i run the following command:

dotnet workload restore

So far so good. Now the project builds again. But my release now fails. I have 3 steps in my release pipeline for my IIS server:

1. Stop app pool
2. deploy my app
3. start my app pool

This worked fine before adding the two statements above. But now i get the following error:

```
Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
Error: Unrecognized argument 'Files\IIS\Microsoft'. All arguments must begin with "-".
Error count: 1.
Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed 
with exit code 4294967295
```

I can't seem to find a solution, so has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i wasn't the only one with the issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17634

I ended up removing web deploy 4.0, and now it works again.
Maybe if I had waited longer, i wouldn't have to remove web deploy 4.0